# Getting number inside quotes

Tags: php, string

I have a string that has a number inside exactly one pair of quotes. How can I get this number using php?

I have tried iterating over the string and or using str_split but I'm not sure how to limit it to what is inside the quotation marks. The fact that the number can be any length makes it even harder.

EDIT: Here is an example

```
Hello this is my "100"th string!,
```

I would need to return `100`;

Comment: Post what have you tried?

Comment: What I have tried was nonsense because I don't know php. If someone could lead me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Comment: pls seee one of the 499,000 results [here](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+cast+string+to+int)

Comment: @andrew The string doesnt only contain integers.

Comment: @Ogen well, your post doesn't say that, perhaps you should post a sample string

Comment: @Ogen could you show your input & expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match()` is a way to get the number from string. Example:

```
$str = 'Hello this is my "100"th string!,';
preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $match);

echo $match[0];
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nT3dB7/1)

Comment: Is there a convenient way to just decrement the number inside the string with a method similar to this? So it would return `Hello this is my "99"th string!,`

Comment: `str_replace()` a way to do this. `preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $match);
$str = str_replace($match[0], $match[0] - 1, $str);
echo $str;`

Comment: This work nicely for positive numbers but it doesn't work for negative numbers because the negative symbol is ignored, is there any way you can incorporate the negative sign?

Comment: `/(-?)\d+/` should be help. `preg_match('/(-?)\d+/', $str, $match);`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo intval('123string');
```

results in 123

Answer (score 1):

trim the quotes from around the string, and php will immediately see the number inside.

```
$str = "'1234'";
$num = trim($str, "'\"");
echo $num + 1;
// => 1235
```

or if you have text as well a string, replace all non-digits with spaces, then have
php automatically parse the string when it is used in an arithmetic expression.

```
$num = preg_replace('/\D/', ' ', $string) + 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

use preg_replace:

```
echo preg_replace("~[^\d+]~", '', 'Hello this is my "100"th string!,');
```